# Read Write array data to plist not working

Tags: ios, plist

```
func readWriteData(){

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let cachePath = paths.first
        //        let bundleName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: cachePath!).URLByAppendingPathComponent("cachedProducts.plist").path
        var isDir : ObjCBool = false
        var error: NSError?
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath!, isDirectory: &isDir) {
            var plistArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            print(plistArray)//retrieving stored data


        }else {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(filePath!, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
                var cachedArray = [AnyObject]()
                cachedArray.append("Harsh")
                let cachedProductarray : NSArray = cachedArray
                cachedProductarray.writeToFile(filePath!, atomically: true)
                //Storing data to plist


            } catch let error as NSError {
                NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
}
```

when i try to print plistArray it's returning nil. Please help me with the solution. I tried this using cachesDirectory and Document Directory it's the same scenario with both

Answer (score 1):

The cache directory is supposed to be created at `cachePath`, not at `filePath`.

Rather than using the quite primitive `writeToFile` method of `NSArray` I'd recommend to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` in conjunction with `NSData`'s `writeToFile:options:error` (still better `writeToURL...`) method to get meaningful error messages.

Comment: var str: NSString = "asgg"
                do{
                    try str.writeToFile(filePath!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                }catch let error as NSError{
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
when i'm trying to write a NSString it's saying - The file “cachedProductsssssss.plist” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Cache"

Comment: Print the paths and check if they are those you're expecting.